# illegal use of ODEINT

Tags: python, numerics, scipy, numpy

given the following system:
$$\frac{dP}{dt} = \alpha P(1-\frac{P}{K}) - \beta P I$$
$$\frac{dI}{dt} = \beta P I - \rho I$$

how do I solve the system numerically. as when I attempt to solve this is the error I get.

> /home/gideon/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:19: RuntimeWarning: >divide by zero encountered in double_scalars

> /home/gideon/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py:247: >ODEintWarning: Illegal input detected (internal error). Run with full_output = 1 to get >quantitative information.
> warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)

here is my code

```
'''
   x[0]  : P(t). population not infected
   x[1]  : I(t). population Infected
   k     : population carrying capacity
   alpha : growth rate
   rho   : death rate
   beta  : infection rate
   t     : time
'''


t = np.linspace(0,20,50)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize = (10,4))
plt.suptitle('Infection Model')

def update_plot(k,alpha,rho,beta):
   ax.clear()

   xprime = lambda x,k,alpha,rho,beta,t: np.array([alpha*x[0]*(1-(x[0]/k))-beta*x[0]*x[1],
                                            beta*x[0]*x[1]-rho*x[1]])
   x0 = np.array([(4/5)*k,k/5])
   x = odeint(xprime,x0,t,args=(k,alpha,rho,beta,))
   y1 = x[:,0]
   y2 = x[:,1]
   ax.plot(t,y1,'b',label = 'P(t)')
   ax.plot(t,y2,'g--',label = 'I(t)')
   plt.legend(loc = 'best')
   plt.show()


k = widgets.FloatSlider(min=1,max = 10 , value =1, description = 'K :')
alpha = widgets.FloatSlider(min=1,max = 10 , value =1, description = r'$\alpha$ :')
rho = widgets.FloatSlider(min=1,max = 10 , value =1, description = r'$\rho$ :')
beta = widgets.FloatSlider(min=1,max = 10 , value =1, description = r'$\beta $ :')

widgets.interactive(update_plot,k=k,alpha=alpha,rho=rho,beta=beta)
```

I'm trying to plot the system for varying parameters but the graphs I am getting are incorrect. i think it is due to the nan values I'm getting in the solution array $x$

Answer (score 1):

```
xprime = lambda x,k,alpha,rho,beta,t:
```

is in the wrong argument order, first are the fixed arguments, then the parameters.

```
xprime = lambda x,t,k,alpha,rho,beta:
```

I'm not sure where the division-by-zero error originates, it could be a consequence of the solution diverging, doing strange things in the step-size controller.